# Notice: register_rest_route was called incorrectly. REST API routes must be registered on the rest_api_init action error in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a problem with an old theme that was developed by our website developer who is no longer available to contact.  We are unable to update to the latest version of Wordpress, due to the following error:

Notice: register_rest_route was called incorrectly. REST API routes must be registered on the rest_api_init action

Looking in our theme functions.php file, I think it's this part that's causing the problem:

```
/**
 * Register menu routes for WP API v2.
 *
 * @since  1.2.0
 */
public function __construct() {

    register_rest_route( self::get_plugin_namespace(), '/menus', array(
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => array( $this, 'get_menus' ),
        )
    ) );

    register_rest_route( self::get_plugin_namespace(), '/menus/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => array( $this, 'get_menu' ),
            'args'     => array(
                'context' => array(
                    'default' => 'view',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ) );

    register_rest_route( self::get_plugin_namespace(), '/menu-locations', array(
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => array( $this, 'get_menu_locations' ),
        )
    ) );

    register_rest_route( self::get_plugin_namespace(), '/menu-locations/(?P<location>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)', array(
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => array( $this, 'get_menu_location' ),
        )
    ) );
}
```

I've tried adding `'permission_callback' => '__return_true',` but this doesn't seem to work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've fixed this by changing the code, using this link as guidance:

https://github.com/unfulvio/wp-api-menus/blob/master/includes/wp-api-menus-v2.php

Answer (score 0):

That's a notice, not an error. It shouldn't stop you from being able to update WordPress.

The class containing your code should be instantianted inside the `rest_api_init` hook, which is currently not and that's why you are getting that notice.

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'the_function_that_instantiates_your_class' );
```